# geting an error "Couldn't fetch mysqli" but not on other computers

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a button that shows a form when clicked. It works in our workstation in class and as well as cloud ide but not on my laptop. Other projects work on my laptop.

I get these errors:

> Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in G:\Web Projects\kmbgis\assets\caseForm.php on line 7
>   Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in G:\Web Projects\kmbgis\assets\caseForm.php on line 8

This is the PHP in **caseForm.php**:

```
<?php
  include('config.php');

  //check any user action
  $action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

  $result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'case_detail'");
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $nextCaseId = $row['Auto_increment']; 

  $result1 = $conn->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'suspect_data'");
  $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
  $nextSuspectId = $row1['Auto_increment'];  

  $result2 = $conn->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'victim_data'");
  $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
  $victimID = $row2['Auto_increment'];  

  //if the user hit the submit button on Case Detail
  if($action == "Add"){

    //Case Details Variables
    $r_unit = $_POST['r_unit'];
    $d_report = $_POST['d_report'];
    $t_report = $_POST['t_report'];
    $crimeCategory = $_POST['crime_category'];
    $r_station = $_POST['r_station'];


    if($crimeCategory == '101'){
      $offenseType = $_POST['crime_type1'];
    }else if($crimeCategory == '102'){
      $offenseType = $_POST['crime_type2'];
    }else if($crimeCategory == '103'){
      $offenseType = $_POST['crime_type3'];
    }else if($crimeCategory == '104'){
      $offenseType = $_POST['crime_type4'];
    }else if($crimeCategory == '105'){
      $offenseType = $_POST['crime_type5'];
    }else{
      $offenseType = "NOT NULL";
    }

    //Insert Values
    $sql = "INSERT INTO case_detail (ReportingUnit,DateOfReporting,TimeOfReporting,SuspectID,OffenseID,CrimeTypeID,VictimID,StationID)
            VALUES('$r_unit','$d_report','$t_report','$nextSuspectId','$offenseType','$crimeCategory','$victimID','$r_station')";

    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
      echo "<script>
                window.location='https://localhost/kmbgis/assets/suspectArea.php?id=".$nextCaseId."';
            </script>";
    } else{
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
  }
  $conn->close();
?>
```

This is inserted in the *casedetail.php* file with `<?php include'caseForm'; ?>` when the button is clicked. And also in that *casedetail.php* I have PHP code that opens the connection, displays a query and closes the connection.

**connect.php** contains:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "wis1-29";
    $password = "Password";
    $dbname = "wis1-29";

    //Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Check connection
    if($conn->connect_errno){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
    }
?>
```

And this is the **casedetails.php** that includes the *caseForm.php*.
For some reason it also doesn't display my *footer.php*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Police Database System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'assets/header.php'; ?>
        <section class="container-fluid">
            <?php include 'assets/loginForm.php'; ?>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h3 class="text-center">Police Database System</h3>
                <h4 class="text-center">Case Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <?php
                    include('assets/config.php');

                    $nameSql = "SELECT 
                                    case_detail.Crime_Case_ID, 
                                    offense.OffenseDescription,
                                    suspect_data.SuspectID,
                                    suspect_data.LastName, 
                                    suspect_data.FirstName, 
                                    case_detail.ReportingUnit,
                                    station.StationName,
                                    station.StationID,
                                    case_detail.DateOfReporting, 
                                    case_detail.TimeOfReporting,
                                    crime.CrimeTypeDescription,
                                    victim_data.vLastName,
                                    victim_data.vFirstName,
                                    victim_data.VictimID
                                FROM case_detail
                                INNER JOIN suspect_data
                                    ON case_detail.SuspectID = suspect_data.SuspectID
                                INNER JOIN offense
                                    ON case_detail.OffenseID = offense.OffenseID
                                INNER JOIN crime
                                    ON case_detail.CrimeTypeID = crime.CrimeTypeID
                                INNER JOIN victim_data
                                    ON case_detail.VictimID = victim_data.VictimID
                                INNER JOIN station
                                    ON case_detail.StationID = station.StationID";

                    $nameResult = $conn->query($nameSql);

                        if ($nameResult->num_rows > 0) {
                            echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Crime Case Number</th>
                                            <th>Crime Commited</th>
                                            <th>Suspect(s)</th>
                                            <th>Reporting unit</th>
                                            <th>Police Station</th>
                                            <th>Date of reporting</th>
                                            <th>Time of reporting</th>
                                            <th>Crime Category</th>
                                            <th>Victim(s)</th>
                                            <th>Update Case</th>
                                            <th>Delete Case</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>";
                            // output data of each row
                            while($row = $nameResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                    echo"<tr>
                                            <td>".$row["Crime_Case_ID"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["OffenseDescription"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["LastName"].", ".$row["FirstName"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["ReportingUnit"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["StationName"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["DateOfReporting"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["TimeOfReporting"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["CrimeTypeDescription"]."</td>
                                            <td>".$row["vLastName"].", ".$row["vFirstName"]."</td>";
                                       echo'<td><a href="assets/caseUpdate.php?id='.$row["Crime_Case_ID"].'&s_id='.$row["SuspectID"].'&v_id='.$row["VictimID"].'&station_id='.$row["StationID"].' "  class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>';
                                       echo'<td><a href="assets/caseDelete.php?id='.$row["Crime_Case_ID"].' " class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>';
                                    echo"</tr>
                                    </tbody>";
                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                        } else {
                            echo "0 results";
                        }
                    $conn->close();
                ?>
                <a class="addbtn btn btn-default" href="#" id="addCase">New Blotter Entry</a>
            </div>
            <div class="center formWrap" id="caseWrap">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm addbtn">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Close 
                </button>
                <h2 class="text-center">Enter new case:</h2>
                <?php include 'assets/caseForm.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </section>

        <?php include 'assets/footer.php'; ?>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you include "connect.php"?

Comment: Hi Nisse! I included it on the casedetail.php where caseForm.php is also included. Within the caseForm i also included the connect.php. Am i doing it right? its like when i query to show a result in casedetail.php i first included the connect.php and then closed it and near the footer part where caseForm is included, i also have a connect.php and then closed it again after it performs the task

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your connection setup, assuming in the config.php, but that error is generally because of connection. The second, non object error, is because of not getting the connection that causes the first error.

Could you post your connection string? should look something like this...

```
$conn = new mysqli("HOST","USER","PASSWORD","TABLE_NAME");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @FuzzyTree The 50 rep constraint on comments makes it impossible to get clarification on the question without actually posting. How else do you suggest I help this person if i can't get clarification? We obviously need to know about the connection string in order to debug an error about it.

Comment: <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "wis1-29";
 $password = "password";
 $dbname = "wis1-29";

 //Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 //Check connection
 if($conn->connect_errno){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
 }
?>

Comment: This looks like it could be a configuration issue on your laptop. Are you seeing the "Failed to connect to MySQL" error? Things to check: 1. Are you sure that the MySQL server running and serving to loacalhost? 2. Do you have mysqli enabled and configured in you php.ini on the laptop?

Comment: Thanks James! No i dont see failed to connect, in fact the other pages work apart from that caseForm.php. i have other pages that inserts, deletes and edits (query) using the same config.php file. Could this be an issue of different versions of php or mysql? i am using the latest Xampp on my laptop and our school uses an older installation. I dont know about cloud 9 ide which is an online ide but it works there too

Answer (score 0):

i installed wamp and everything worked! I reinstalled the same xampp version on a different boot and it didnt work so the problem could be the mysql version. I updated the PHP version from 5.5.9 and still didnt work so i tried updating the mysql in xampp but failed to do so. So i just decided to download the newer version of xampp.

The xampp version that didnt work is 1.8.3 with a 5.5.9 PHP and 5.6.16 MYSQL the Wamp that worked has a PHP 5.5.12 and 5.6.17 MYSQL

Comment: Downloaded the latest version of xampp with 5.6 PHP version and still does not work! Anyone?